# Paramiko not working

Tags: ssh, python, sshd

I have paramiko 2.7.2 and OpenSSH_7.9p1. Whenever I try anything I get the same error:

```
SSHException: Incompatible ssh server (no acceptable ciphers)
```

As I understand everything should be working fine, because I defined my ciphers both in **sshd_config** and **ssh_config**.

sshd_config:

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

ssh_config:

```
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
```

ssh -Q cipher:

```
3des-cbc
aes128-cbc
aes192-cbc
aes256-cbc
rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
aes128-ctr
aes192-ctr
aes256-ctr
aes128-gcm@openssh.com
aes256-gcm@openssh.com
chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
```

paramiko.Transport._preferred_ciphers:

```
('aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-cbc', 'aes192-cbc', 'aes256-cbc', 'blowfish-cbc', '3des-cbc')
```

What can I do about it to make it work?

Comment: Are you connecting to the localhost?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, yep, it happens when I try to connect to localhost.